# Project Server 2010 : getAdata: The operation has timed out

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, project-server

[image]

This is Microsoft project server and this site workflow can't get data from the SSRS but SSRS have report fetched known Funding authorization but this workflow throws an error called getAData: The operation has timed out

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue related to the Account permissions. weather the account being used to pull the data from the DB is not the account having permissions on that web part.

check the site settings and then look the PWA user and check if that user account has permissions on the PWA and reporting DB.

Comment: I checked with the permissions and the site is showing the Webadmin access and i granted Full access and it doesn't change anything AZHar